# how to save multiple radio button in database using php without save button value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, radio-group

how to save multiple radio button in database using php without save button value.

my code :

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {   
    if ($key <> 'user_id') {
        $bidder_interst_insert="INSERT INTO bidder_interest_list(id, bidder_id, bidder_interest_name) VALUES ('','$user_id','$val')";
        $bidder_interst_insert_result = mysql_query($bidder_interst_insert);
        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
            $interest_list_success = "Thank you Successfull insert your interst list.";
            $_SESSION['interest_list_success_msg'] = $interest_list_success;
        } else {
            $insert_error = "interst list Insert Error.";
            $_SESSION['insert_error_msg'] = $insert_error;
            header("location:interest_list.php");
        }
    }
}
```

This code work but database extra save in save button value how to solved this problem??

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Can i view Your Html Code?

Comment: Yes completely agree with @tadman, but in current code if you want to unset save button value, you can use unset($_POST['name-of-save-button']); And then $data = $_POST; foreach($data as $key => $val){//your code here}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ){
```

You are directly looping the `$_POST`, so the SAVE button value is also saving in the database. Take the values individually instead of looping the whole `$_POST`, then the SAVE button value won't be saved in the database.

And moreover you are using `mysql` functions which are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

EDIT::
Just take it the same way as u took `user_id` ==>  `$variablename = $_POST['fieldname'];`

---

EDIT:::
Let me suppose i have a form like this

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="A" checked="checked" />A <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="B" checked="checked" />B <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="C" checked="checked" />C <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="D" checked="checked" />D <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="E" checked="checked" />E <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="F" checked="checked" />F <br />

        <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

then i can do it like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $products = $_POST['products'];
        foreach($products as $key => $value)
        {
            $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl(product) VALUES('$value')");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: no because this is a big project..!!
this is all work are mysql not mysqli 
thanks.
please give me example....??
i will try it :)

Comment: I've given an example.. I think ur requirement is a bit similar to this.. Once try..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`unset($_POST['name-of-save-button']);
 $data = $_POST;
 foreach ( $data as $key => $val ){//your code here}`

Comment: @illease this should work definitely, you can check it by print_r($_POST); unset($_POST['any-post-field-you-want-to-unset']);print_r($_POST);